# Django forms: How to simply include all attributes in the associated model

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I am working through how to use Django's forms (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/#more-on-fields) and I can't see a way to generate a form structure that is based on a defined Model. In Symfony, I remember I was able to get my form to automatically include **all** parameters of <kbd>myModel</kbd> (for example) even if any new attributes were later added to the model.

For example:

```
class myModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    created=models.DateTimeField(null=False)
    modified=models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    myParameter= models.IntegerField(default=None)
    // ... plus many more parameters
```

Rather than having to manually type corresponding rows into my `class myModelForm(forms.Form):`, I'm looking/hoping for a 'catch all'.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

```
from django.forms import ModelForm

class myModelForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = myModel
        fields = '__all__'
```

More details [selecting-the-fields-to-use](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/modelforms/#selecting-the-fields-to-use)

Comment: `exclude = []` works too.

Comment: but `fields = '__all__'` should be more readable isn't it? )

Comment: I prefer setting an empty list instead of a magic string, but are fine with both :)